# Is there an easier way to code this?

Tags: regex, powershell, exchange-server-2010

Through using help from this group I am starting to get my head around regular expressions.

I have this script that takes the size of an exchange mailbox, splits out the bytes size as a number and formats it to 3 decimal places.

It all work fine and I have the answers I want but being as I am new to regular expressions I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing it as it looks messy.

```
    $size=Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user| Select itemcount,totalitemsize
    $size = $size.TotalItemSize
    $mbxsize=$size -replace '[.*(]',''
    $mbxsize=$mbxsize -replace '\d*\s\w+\s',''
    $mbxsize=$mbxsize -replace '[bytes)]',''
    $mbxsize=$mbxsize -replace ',',''
    $mbxsize="{0:N3}" -f ($mbxsize/1024/1024)
```

TIA

Andy

Comment: What does `$size` contain before you start doing the replaces on it? Be easier if you could show the data how you want it before and after applying the regex

Answer (score 0):

you can convert `totalitemsize` value to MB  directly in this way:

```
$size= Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user | 
     Select itemcount, @{n='totalitemsize';e={$_.totalitemsize.value.toMB()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply the regex to get down to just the byte count (with commas) to this:

```
-replace '.+\(([0-9,]+)\s.+','$1'
```

and you can chain the replace operators, so you can simplify the whole process to:

```
$mbxsize= $size -replace '.+\(([0-9,]+)\s.+','$1' -replace ','
$mbxsize="{0:N3}" -f ($mbxsize/1MB)
```